# Two simultaneous returns in python recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, palindrome

How can I implement the following code in Python?

```
class Solution:
    def p(self, s:str):
        if len(s)<= 1:
            return True
        elif s[0] != s[-1]:
            return False
        return self.p(s[1:-1])

    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        if self.p(s):
            return s
        return self.longestPalindrome(s[1:])
        return self.longestPalindrome(s[:-1])
```

I want that both return statement works simultaneously and whichever becomes True first will return the answer.

Comment: See [Intro to threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Comment: Which method? Both potentially look like you want to double return.

Comment: @jarmod I suspect that isn't what the OP wants

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, on re-read, I think you're probably correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen, but could be an experiment to try working with `return (self.longestPalindrome(s[1:]), self.longestPalindrome(s[:-1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return multiple values from a single function using the syntax:

```py
def func():
    return "foo", "bar"

a,b = func()
print(a)  # prints: foo
print(b)  # prints: bar
```

I'm fairly sure if you return two recursive calls to a function then it will evaluate the left one first, but I'm not certain about that so I wouldn't count on it.

As to the second part of your question of running both simultaniously and only returning the one that finishes first, the best you can do is use multi-threading and spinning off each call of `self.longestPalindrome()` into a new thread. This still won't do exactly what you want because you are still limited by the number of threads your computer can handle. I'll let you figure out how to do that if that is your goal I'll re-link the intro to threading mention by jarmod [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

The problem with your question is that a computer can't know which option will finish first without running each option until it reaches a stop condition, and a computer can only do a limited number of things simultaneously. This means that while you can calculate which of the two sides will be faster, you need to run both sides one at a time to do so. While you could run the first couple recursive steps in parallel, each step would double the number of threads you'd need and most modern computers can only handle between 4-16 threads at one time (you can spawn more, they'll just wait until a "slot" is free), which means you only get 2-4 steps in before you are no longer running things simultaneously.

There are some options to speed this up by adding rules to prune some possible branches. If you think of your recursive function as a series of branching paths, you can look for cases where one path would be obviously wrong, or at least likely wrong and add a rule that skips said path. The rules are known as heuristics and are essentially estimations of the correctness of one path or another, and employing them would let you potentially find the fastest path to a correct answer more quickly.

In general though unless you are trying to find the longest palindrome in a very large body of text, I would just accept that you're going to need to go down each recursive path one after another instead of being able to go down all of them simultaneously as if your only goal is to find the longest palindrome you should be able to find it in a reasonable amount of time even if you only rely on a single thread to execute the entire program.